# Slide Menu Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a class called "home" and a class called "menu" with tableview, in home I create a button to push a menu,  when I click on the button I make the frame move and appear the menu but I can't click on the table view cell of menu, the priority is the home. how can I change and make this work?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];
    menuViewController = [[ITMenuViewController alloc] init];
    menuViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 568);
    [self.view addSubview:menuViewController.view];

    btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(pushMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitle:@"push" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 300, 240, 40);
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    btn.tag = 1;
    btn.clipsToBounds = YES;
    //set other button properties here.
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)pushMenu {

    if (menuViewController.view.frame.origin.x < 0 && btn.tag == 2) {
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{ 

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        menuViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 568);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             btn.tag = 1;
        }];
     }

     if (menuViewController.view.frame.origin.x >= 0 && btn.tag == 1)
     {
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 320, 568);
            menuViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width + 0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 568);
            [self.view.layer setCornerRadius:4];
            [self.view.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
            [self.view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
            [self.view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.5f)];        
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            btn.tag = 2;
        }];
    }}
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: ok, you can check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check PPRevealSideViewController. It will help you for what you want https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController.

You can add your home view controller in your appdelegate like this:

```
HomeViewController *home = [[HomeViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home];
_revealSideViewController = [[PPRevealSideViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nav];

self.window.rootViewController = _revealSideViewController;
```

And push your manu viewcontroller like this:

```
MenuViewController *menu = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil ];
[self.revealSideViewController pushViewController:menu onDirection:PPRevealSideDirectionBottom animated:YES];
```

**EDIT**

To add PPRevealSideViewController as a submodule to your project go to terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/MyApplication
# If this is a new project, initialize git...
$ git init
$ git submodule add git://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController.git vendor/PPRevealSideViewController
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

-In your XCode Project, take the PPRevealSideViewController.h and .m from PPRevealSideViewController folder and drag them into your project.

-Import PPRevealSideViewController.h file to your PCH file or your AppDelegate file.

-Add the QuartzCore Framework.

-Start using this new controller!

Comment: I try use but the file #import <PPHelpMe/PPHelpMe.h> not found and if I delete other problems appear

Comment: How did you install it? Through cocoapods or as a submodule?

Comment: Well, for me works fine as I installed with cocoapods. Probably you install it as submodule, and I cannot help you with this. But I m sure that something you have missed from install steps.

Comment: Since my answer helped you, could you accept it. Enjoy it :)